# Modify range of Hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, macros

So, I have a spreadsheet that I have sent out to several of our staff asking to update certain fields/columns. I have a Document Link field (Column G) which links them a folder in our F: Drive which they can use to help populate the necessary fields.

The spreadsheets which I want them to complete are also in this F:Drive. However, I noticed each of the document links no longer work, and when I check the link under Edit Hyperlink, I notice instead of the desired "*F:\Procurement..." I have my home drive "+\NSH-HDRIVES1..." as the header,

- F:\Procurement\Contracts\Alco...xxx...
- \NSH-HDRIVES1\Contracts\Alco...xxx...

I have hundreds of these lines with document links that need "\NSH-HDRIVES1" replaced with "F:".

Is there some kind of VBA Macro that will let me do this? I have little experience and time to learn VBA Macros at this point so any help would be greatly appreciated. Note each link is different and goes to a different folder within our F:Drive, all I need is to change the prefix.

Thanks and sorry for any duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code may help, but it is set up to only work on the ActiveSheet.  If your hyperlinks are in multiple workbooks and multiple worksheets you will need to loop through them all.

```
For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
    h.Address = Replace(h.Address, "\NSH-HDRIVES1\", "F:\Procurement\")
    h.TextToDisplay = Replace(h.TextToDisplay, "\NSH-HDRIVES1\", "F:\Procurement\")
Next
```

Comment: @Thomas2016 you might need to add this too `h.TextToDisplay = Replace(h.TextToDisplay, "\NSH-HDRIVES1\", "F:\Procurement\")`

Comment: Brilliant, I have a master sheet that I can divy up, so its all fixed up now.